# SFTP in XAMPP not working

Tags: php, xampp, sftp, phpseclib

FTP is working fine but when i try to use sftp issues comes.

i am using this [link](http://secure.nerdster.com.au/knowledgebase/10075/How-to-enable-SFTP-with-Filezilla-Server.html) to configure sftp in xampp.

Using [this](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) link for sftp connection.

My code to connect is,

```
            include 'Net/SFTP.php';
            $sftp = new Net_SFTP('myhost');
            if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
                echo 'Login Failed';
                }
            else
               echo $sftp->get('test.csv');
```

i am getting 'Login Failed' error. can anyone help me in this.

Comment: what exactly "myhost" is? Do you have SFTP server there? Also do you have firewall open port 990? Error logs?

Comment: i using xampp and configure sftp using this link http://secure.nerdster.com.au/knowledgebase/10075/How-to-enable-SFTP-with-Filezilla-Server.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i am using this link to configure sftp in xampp.

No, you aren't. From that link:

"Filezilla Server does not support FTP via SFTP" and "You have now secured Filezilla FTP server for use with only a FTPS connection".

If you want to use SFTP then you have to install an SFTP server. FTPS is different.

Comment: OpenSSH is the industry standard.